# Reviewing one's own posts

Tags: feature-request

It seems a bit foolish to have users review their own posts. Would it not be fairer to have others do that?

Screenshot:
[image]

As indirect evidence, I have also deleted posts. This is not possible for me to do, unless I was the post author.

In addition - and this is far less significant - it seems to me that the same should be true if the reviewer had the last edit.

Comment: Screenshot or it didn't happen!

Comment: @DanielBeck, Done.

Comment: There are actually 3 of mine on [this](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&page=12&pagesize=50&filter=all&customsort=newestfirst&no-random=1) page (subject to change, move to different pages, or getting reviewed)

Comment: I guess you just need to write higher quality posts then :-)

Comment: I saw some of yours too :)

Comment: \*Gasp\* Impossible! But if I were a frequent user of `/review`, I would have seen them too and could have fixed my posts.

Comment: I think (but am not sure that it takes two different people to review something before it goes away.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this causes any harm; the low quality algorithm is impartial in that it only looks at a basic heuristic, and doesn't factor ownership in.

Besides, this means you can be encouraged to improve your own posts! :)

Comment: You don't think that there are issues of impartiality?

Comment: @soandos It's an indicator for you that a post might be poor. Of course you can just decide "It's mine, it's good", but you have a similar problem with any post: "That's a post by user X, I'm sure he knows what he's doing".

Comment: @soandos, he’s talking specifically about the *automatic*, blind low-quality flagging routine. Many people probably won’t even realize that their post is (mathematically) considered low quality, but once they see it flagged, they may realize it and improve it. User flags on the other hand may trigger a more defensive behavior…